# How to generate color code usage hierarchy recursively in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

when I find usage color code , android studio just shows the usage of that color code in project , for example shows color1 used in backgrounddrawable1.xml and so on but it does not show the usage of backgrounddrawable1.xml unless I find usage that file separately but
I wanna know Is it possible to generate the hierarchy of usage recursively like dependencies graph but for color codes ?

please let me know if any one has any ideas thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help.

run this using python.

this is an starting point and can be improved

```
from lxml import etree
import os

def explore_xml(xml_file, depth=0):
    tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    print(f"{'  ' * depth}File: {xml_file}")

    for element in root.iter():
        if "color" in element.text:
            print(f"{'  ' * (depth + 1)}Color used: {element.text}")

    for include_tag in root.iter("include"):
        layout = include_tag.get("layout")
        if layout:
            included_file = find_included_file(xml_file, layout)
            if included_file:
                explore_xml(included_file, depth + 1)

def find_included_file(parent_file, layout):
    # Implement logic to find included XML file based on your project structure
    included_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(parent_file), f"{layout}.xml")
    if os.path.exists(included_file):
        return included_file
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_xml_file = "path/to/main/layout.xml"  # Replace with your main XML file
    explore_xml(main_xml_file)
```